# Gradient of a function g(x)

Tags: partial-derivative, gradient-flows

I was told that to calculate the vector that is normal to a surface as shown in the image (please ignore red markings) you take the gradient (partial derivative w/ respect to x), transpose. I do not understand why this is done. How does the gradient, transpose give you the normal vector?

[image: Vector that is normal to the surface]

Answer (score 2):

Given a smooth surface consisting of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where  $g(x)=0.$   Define a curve $x(t)$ on the surface. Then the tangent vectors $x'(t)$  to the curve are are also tangent to the surface.  Also note that 
$$
\frac{d}{dt} g(x(t))=0 \ \ \ \Rightarrow \text{ (ChainRule)} \ \ \  \nabla g(x(t)) \cdot x'(t) = 0,
$$ 
implying that the gradient $\nabla g(x)$ is orthogonal to the tangent vector at $x.$

Comment: So from my understanding, you are saying that the derivative produces the tangent vector to g(x) and if the derivative is equal to 0, then that implies that the gradient is orthogonal to that tangent vector? In this case?

Comment: I just found a video that seems to have the same explanaition as you do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Op0RG7tPv0   I have a clearer understanding now.

Answer (score 0):

Your graph is the isoline $g(x) = 0$
$$
0 = g \Rightarrow 0 = dg = \mbox{grad } g \cdot du
$$
so $\mbox{grad } g$ is orthogonal to the displacement $du$ if one follows $g$.

The diagram also shows that $\mbox{grad } g$ points towards the region of positive $g$.